# Security issue with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Firstly I tried adding multiple ifmodule but it does not work.

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://domainurl1.com
</ifModule>

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://domainurl2.com
</ifModule>
```

When try to add multiple ifmodule only last one(http://domainurl2.com) works others not.
then I try following code it works but i think it is not secure to allow everyone

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
       Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: “*”
    </ifModule>
```

I have 5 domain that i have to allow.
Are there any solutions for adding multiple domains that i want to allow?

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want a quick fix

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
 Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://domainurl1.com"
 Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://domainurl2.com"
</ifModule>
```

However, this is not the recommended solution by W3C, instead you should make the server read the Origin header from the client, then compare it to a list of allowed domains and finally send the value of the Origin header back to the client as the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. Check http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-origin-response-hea for more details.